# How to convert a nested hashtable to PSObjects in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

If you have a hashtable containing nested hashtables, how to convert that to a PsObject recursively?

```
@{
    Foo = @{
        Bar = @{
            Key = 'Value'
            Test = 1
        }
    }
}
```

The result should be

```
$_.Foo.Bar.Key = 'Value'
$_.Foo.Bar.Test = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to create a recursive function:

```
function ConvertTo-PsObject {
    param (
        [hashtable] $Value
    )

    foreach ( $key in $Value.Keys | Where-Object { $Value[$_].GetType() -eq @{}.GetType() } ) {
        $Value[$key] = ConvertTo-PsObject $Value[$key]
    }

    New-Object PSObject -Property $Value | Write-Output
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it which hasn't been mentioned so far, and is more appropriate in many cases is to use New-Object PSObject.

```
$a = @{
    Foo = @{
        Bar = @{
            Key = 'Value'
            Test = 1
        }
    }
}
$b = New-Object -Type PSObject -Property $a
```

Doing it this way makes it work correctly with `Format-Table` for instance, and probably other places too.

Answer (score 0):

Cast it to a `[PsCustomObject]`:

```
$a = [PsCustomObject]@{
    Foo = @{
        Bar = @{
            Key = 'Value'
            Test = 1
        }
    }
}

$a.Foo.Bar.Key   # --> "Value"
$a.Foo.Bar.Test  # --> 1
```